# Firestore query on collectiongroup fails on rules as described by documentation

Tags: node.js, firebase, ecmascript-6

I am struggling with firestore security rules when querying data in a collection group. I have narrowed down my search to the case from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_collection_group_queries_based_on_a_field). and I am using the rules emulator to test my rules.

please see my example below:
I use the Firebase testenvironment to set up a test case, so my data looks like this.

```
forums/
   forum_id/
      posts/
          post_id2:{
            author:"another_autor" 
            published:true 
          }
   forum_id2/
      posts/
          post_id:{
            author:"id_authedDB" 
            published:true 
          }
```

I run a query on groupCollection "posts" to return me all documents where 'author' is "id_authedDB". I expect it to return only 1 of the 2 posts that meets the query condition, as the query matches the what is allowed by the rules. However, the emulator tells me fields 'published' or 'author' are undefined

I hope anyone can help me with this,

best regards,
Tim

## terminal result

[image]

## example

my rules are like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Returns `true` if the requested post is 'published'
    // or the user authored the post
    function authorOrPublished() {
      return resource.data.published == true || request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
    }
    match /{path=**}/posts/{post} {

      // Anyone can query published posts
      // Authors can query their unpublished posts
      allow list: if authorOrPublished();

      // Anyone can retrieve a published post
      // Authors can retrieve an unpublished post
      allow get: if authorOrPublished();
    }

    match /forums/{forumid}/posts/{postid} {
      // Only a post's author can write to a post
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.author;
    }
  }
}
```

and my test is like this ( based on the v9 tests in the [testing quickstart repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-testing) )

```
const { readFileSync, createWriteStream } = require('fs');
const http = require("http");

const testing = require('@firebase/rules-unit-testing');
const { initializeTestEnvironment, assertFails, assertSucceeds } = testing;

const { doc, setDoc, setLogLevel, getDocs, query, collectionGroup, where } = require('firebase/firestore');

/** @type testing.RulesTestEnvironment */
let testEnv;

const projectId = "builder-d0c31"
const host = '127.0.0.1'
const port = 8080

before(async () => {
  // Silence expected rules rejections from Firestore SDK. Unexpected rejections
  // will still bubble up and will be thrown as an error (failing the tests).
  setLogLevel('error');

  testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
  projectId,
  firestore: {
    host,
    port,
    rules: readFileSync('firestore.rules', 'utf8')
  },
  });

});

after(async () => {
  // Delete all the FirebaseApp instances created during testing.
  // Note: this does not affect or clear any data.
  await testEnv.cleanup();

  // Write the coverage report to a file
  const coverageFile = 'firestore-coverage.html';
  const fstream = createWriteStream(coverageFile);
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { host, port } = testEnv.emulators.firestore;
    const quotedHost = host.includes(':') ? `[${host}]` : host;
    http.get(`http://${quotedHost}:${port}/emulator/v1/projects/${testEnv.projectId}:ruleCoverage.html`, (res) => {
      res.pipe(fstream, { end: true });

      res.on("end", resolve);
      res.on("error", reject);
    });
  });

  console.log(`View firestore rule coverage information at ${coverageFile}\n`);
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  await testEnv.clearFirestore();
});



/////////////////////////
// Main test starts here
/////////////////////////

describe("posts", () => {

  it('should allow authedDB to get post', async function() {

    // create a user
    const uid = 'id_authedDB'
    const authedDB = testEnv.authenticatedContext(uid).firestore();

    // Setup: Create documents in DB for testing (bypassing Security Rules).
    await testEnv.withSecurityRulesDisabled(async (context) => {

      const db = context.firestore()
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'forums/forum_id/posts/post_id'), {author:uid, published:true})
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'forums/forum_id2/posts/post_id2'), {author:'another_autor', published:true})
    });

    await assertSucceeds(getDocs(query(collectionGroup(authedDB, 'posts', where("author", "==", uid)))));
  });

});
```